# Query All Distinct , wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my application each activity has a sport, and a user has many activities, i'm trying to list all the distinct sports that a user practices through activities.The name of the activity is also the name of the sport which the activity is associated with.

Its giving me the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

def show_other
 @account = Account.find(params[:id])
@activity = @account.activities.last(20)
@sports = @activity.select(:name).distinct //error here//
end
```

How i call this view:

```
    <%= link_to friend.name, pages_show_other_path(:id => friend.id) %>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last() will always return an array and you can't use that select on an array.

Try something like this:

```
Activity.where(account_id: params[:id]).pluck(:name).last(20).uniq
```

Comment: @MMrj, You could also improve the performance by .order and .limit on database level instead of returning hundreds of rows and then only get the last 20 of them

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?:

```
def show_other
  @account = Account.joins(:activities).find(params[:id])
  @activities = @account.activities.uniq.last(20)
  @sports = @activities.map(&:name)
end
```